# C++ References and Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have the following code in my program for a blackjack game:

```
Player *p;
Deck *d = new Deck();
Hand *playerHand = new Hand(), *dealerHand = new Hand();
p = get_Simple();  //This returns a pointer to an instance of a Simple Player for my game
Card dealerCard = d->deal();
p->draw(dealerCard, playerHand);
```

draw is defined as

```
virtual bool draw(Card dealer, const Hand &player);
```

When I try to run this code, I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Player::draw(Card&, Hand*&);
note: candidates are: virtual bool Player::draw(Card, const Hand&);
```

Comment: `T* x = new T()` is, like, never a good idea in C++. Why not just `Hand playerHand`?

Comment: `new T()` just sets a few default values for each of the objects, which wouldn't be done if I just called `Hand playerHand`.  I guess I could set them manually, but it seemed easier to just use the pointers.  Judging by the answers here, I might've been wrong, haha.

Comment: If `Hand playerHand;` and `Hand* playerHand = new playerHand();` produce different objects, then you can fix that in your constructor by initializing your POD sub-objects.  Otherwise you can do `Hand playerHand = Hand();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick-fix would be to match the call with the signature:

```
p->draw(dealerCard, *playerHand);
```

The correct way would be to go about your code and get rid of dynamic allocation and raw pointers, replacing them with smart pointers.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work!  I'm not familiar with smart pointers, and since this is for a class where performance isn't important (yet), this solution works just fine.  But once I'm a bit more experienced with C++, I might come back and try to rewrite this code to be more efficient.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @camdroid it's not about efficiency, it's about writing good C++ code instead of C code in a C++ compiler.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Is there some resource I can use to see some common C++ standards?  I'm more familiar with Java than C++, so I don't really know what good practices are with pointers.

Comment: @camdroid http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Thanks very much - I'll try to check out some of those books in the list.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear (after seeing it a couple of times):

> error: no matching function for call to 'Player::draw(Card&, Hand*&);
>   note: candidates are: virtual bool Player::draw(Card, const Hand&);

In the code you are trying to pass a `Card` and a `Hand*` to a function, but the compiler did not find an overload that takes those. The closest it got is a function that takes a `Card` and a `const Hand&`.

You need to dereference the pointer to get to the object:

```
p->draw(dealerCard, *playerHand);
```

Alternatively consider whether you need to hold all objects by pointer or not. Code is much simpler if you avoid pointers.